# Django with Gunicorn different ways to deploy

Tags: python, django, nginx, gunicorn

I've been reading about deploying Django with gunicorn and I wanted to give it a try.

I have found at least 3 ways of running a server with gunicorn and django:

1. `gunicorn [OPTIONS] [APP_MODULE] # tested locally and worked fine`
2. `python managy.py run_gunicorn   # also works fine locally`
3. `gunicorn_django [OPTIONS] [SETTINGS_PATH] # I have an error due to apps/ location`

I have Apache with nginx (serving static files) in production at the moment, works fine but is a litle slow and want to try Gunicorn. The first 2 options worked fine locally with nginx serving static files.

I want to know a couple if things:

1. What is the difference between any option above ?
2. What is the proper instruction to run in `PRODUCTION` environments ?

Thank you guys.

Comment: `give me some error on my apps` what error exactly? And just FYI, in production, you should have `DEBUG = False`, and when `DEBUG` is `False`, Django doesn't serve static files. You need your server software to take care of them.

Comment: @Bibhas, the error I get, it's related to the location of the apps on the project, not really relevant to the question I think. Thanks for letting me know that Django does not serve static on DEBUG = False, that's new.

Comment: What is your settings path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `gunicorn_django [OPTIONS] myproject` if you use `myproject.settings`

Comment: You mean for production deplyment ?

Comment: Not recommended.  From the docs: "If you run Django 1.4 or newer, it’s highly recommended to simply run your application with the WSGI interface using the gunicorn command."